# Change definition of exit codes in bash script

Tags: bash, exit-code

I'm attempting to run a simple bash script which checks the available space on the volumes attached to a Linux machine, then sends the result of any volumes to the output if it is over a particular threshold. The idea behind this is to monitor various servers so that we receive notifications when the volumes are getting full.

The mechanism we'd like to use is Jenkins, so what we need is a job that we can run every minute or so, and that job to fail if any volume is over 80%.

I'm using a script like this at the moment:

```
df -H | grep -vE '^Filesystem|tmpfs|cdrom' | awk '{ if ( $5+0 > 80 ) print $5 " " $1 }' | while read output;
do
  echo $output
  usep=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $1}' | cut -d'%' -f1  )
  partition=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $2 }' )
done
```

This script successfully results in the output I need:

```
83% /dev/xvda1
92% /dev/xvdb
```

But this is where I am stuck. After much mucking around I've concluded my best bet would be to cause a failure if there is any output - as expected if I up the threshold to 95 (for example), the output is empty. However, I can't figure out a way to tell Jenkins this is the definition of a failure, because of course the exit status is 0, which Jenkins correctly interprets to mean success.

Can I change this so that this command has an exit status of 0 if there is **no output**, and a failure status if there is **any output**? I think that will allow me to do what I am trying to do.

Comment: That's not a typical use-case for Jenkins

Comment: We use Jenkins to manage infrastructure so it's typical for us.

Comment: Do you actually *need* that output, or can you simply make `awk` have a non-zero exit status if it sees a high percentage instead of producing any output? `awk '{ if ($5+0 > 80) exit 1}'`.

Comment: I don't need the output, this is just where I've found myself, as someone inexperienced with this type of scripting. I really just need the a non-zero status if it's over the set threshold.

Comment: This is the question I should have been asking, but what I found online didnt take me to that. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the output to a temp var. If it has size, exit with a return code.

Also, drop that extraneous `grep`. You're already using `awk`.

```
flag=0
while read output
do flag=1
   echo "$output"
done < <( df -H | awk '
 /^Filesystem|tmpfs|cdrom/ { next; }
 { if ( $5+0 > 50 ) print $5 " " $1 }'
)
exit $flag
```

Better, with the help of smarter folk -

```
df -H | awk '
 /^Filesystem|tmpfs|cdrom/ { next; }
 { if ( $5+0 > 80 ) print $5 " " $1; exit 1; }'
```

Comment: I'm still getting a 0 code whether there is output or not, so not managing to get a failure.

Comment: duh. Running in a pipe subshell. Sorry. gimme a sec

Comment: Particular reason for going for that fix, vs the process-substitution inversion approach? Needing a temporary file seems a little unfortunate.

Comment: Not braining so good today. Would love to see a quick example, though it looks like chepner has cut to the chase and made the exercise largely a moot point, lol

Comment: @PaulHodges that updated answer is giving me what I need - exit status of 1, which Jenkins is flagging as unstable. Thanks so much for that, gives me a place to start researching a couple of new topics as well.

Comment: `while read output; do flag=1; ...; done < <(awk ...)`, as described in [BashFAQ #24](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Comment: Thanks, Charles. I never liked that structure, but this is what I needed to see. You rock, as always.

Comment: You could `if (...) { print; exit 1; }` in chepner's awk code to get both the output *and* the nonzero exit status. :)

Comment: COLLABORATION! :D